# UI rendering like I'm not signed in

Tags: bug, login, sign-up

I am seeing a sign up prompt when I am clearly signed in. Is this happening to anyone else?

[image]

Chrome version: Version 53.0.2785.143 m

Windows 10 Enterprise

Add ons: Pocket, Vimium, and Webex

Comment: I'm not getting this. Browser, version, any add-ons, etc.?

Comment: @BSMP my bad should have included initially.

Comment: No repro on Vivaldi 1.6.689.40 (yes, I am one of the six users)  Windows 7 Home Premium w/ add-ons disabled.

Comment: No repro on Chrome version: 55.0.2883.87 m, IE 11, or Firefox 50.1.0 on Windows 7.