# Sign up present when logged in

Tags: bug

I seem to be getting a sign up banner. First I got a large one - I tried clicking take the tour to see what happened out of curiosity, it didn't do anything so I clicked dismiss. Now I've still got a sign up banner. However I've been logged in through this process:

[image]

Comment: Why does your [freehand circle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/164356) look like an arrow?

Comment: Possibly the same as [Why, as a logged-in user, am I being invited to join Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342189/1529630)

Comment: Does this go away if you delete the "hero" cookie as per the question linked by Oriol?

Comment: @Floern At least it is red...

Comment: @Floern: The arrow is composed of little, pixel-sized freehand circles.

Comment: @DavidG yeah, removing that cookie seems to clear it out.

Comment: also duplicating mine: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341262/ui-rendering-like-im-not-signed-in