# Why, as a logged-in user, am I being invited to join Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed

While it's very nice to be invited to join "a community of 6.6 million programmers, just like [me]" it seems a little bit odd to join that community of "6.6 million programmers" when it already *includes* me.

I am logged in, viewing the home-page of [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/); the left section of the image, below, shows my active (albeit pixelised) inbox, and the right shows a slightly less inbox-obscured view of the page as I currently see it:

[image]

Admittedly there are no free-hand red-circles, for which I can only apologise. But what gives? Is this a result of the recent network problem or a bug of another kind?

Comment: Have you logged out, cleared your cookies and cache, and logged back in?

Comment: I'm getting this too. Additionally, clicking "take the 2 minute tour" doesn't do anything, just links back to the homepage where the banner still shows.

Comment: @j08691: no, I haven't; but since this has never happened before it never occurred to me that I'd have to. I've done a routine ctrl + F5, but I've not deliberately cleared the complete cache and stored assets.

Comment: [Yes](https://twitter.com/StackStatus).

Comment: SO was just down and in RO mode so this may be an artifact of that.

Comment: Kudos to @j08691, clearing cookies solved the issue.

Comment: This was solved when I deleted the `hero` cookie.

Comment: I had this happen a few weeks ago. I logged out and logged back in to fix it.

Comment: When in doubt, log out, log back in again, and don't forget to reboot for good measure! Wait this isn't Windows 

Comment: @brandonscript I’ve always found that throwing the computer out of the window and buying a new one almost always fixes any lingering issues :P

Comment: Where things go awry here though though, is the buying of the new one. You're much safer if you stop after the throwing out the window part, I'd say.

Comment: @brandonscript So turning Stack Overflow off and back on again fixes the problem?

Comment: That Craver guy must have titanium ones. I can think of a few less stressfull jobs than managing SO's servers or something.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Think of how terrifying it would be for servers to start throwing errors, and you can't google them to find the StackOverflow answers!

Comment: Reproduced. I've been signed in for months. https://i.stack.imgur.com/so4JA.png

Comment: As I had been, @pgmann, though while the question still exists, in the hopeful anticipation of an official response, the solution appears to be to either clear cookies, or simply clear the "`hero` cookie" (which means nothing to me, so I went with clearing all cookies). Alternatively logging out and then logging back in also works (these suggestions from previous comments).

Comment: @DavidThomas Dismissing the message worked for me.

Comment: The system has simply detected that you have fewer sock puppets than the average troll and is encouraging you to make more accounts.

Comment: This happened to me yesterday after a brief period when the site was in read-only mode. It seemed at the time that it was leftover via a cookie stored while read-only and it stayed around until I dismissed it, and then was left with another smaller message beneath which I also dismissed even though I was already logged in.

Comment: Same problem here, but I've had it for a couple weeks now and everything in the interface shows as though I'm not logged in. If I reload the home page, sometimes even a couple times, it works. Sometimes it requires hitting "Log in". I was going to report soon.

Comment: so much unfunny clutter.  it's a bug and hopefully will be fixed.

Comment: "*\[So\] much unfunny clutter*" - welcome to Meta, @Joe; this is where we *don't* hate fun (for given values of 'fun'). :)

Comment: @JF Hence the name _Windows_.

Comment: Btw don't join that community, I hear bad things about it. Especially their "meta site", it is full with clutter and spam, and they don't take bug reports seriously.

Comment: @Lundin: so I've heard, chatter and nonsense abounds, and everything takes 6-8 weeks...sigh.

Comment: I can take the spam, fun and nonsense. But not the free-hand red-circles absence. >_>

Comment: Try deleting your account then opening a new one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, that was an error in the code and indeed, it was related to cookies. I just fixed it, but now I'm hungry and [that's the fault of blueprintChris](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/342300/4574).

Comment: Thanks, @Konamiman, much appreciated! As for hunger, if you ask Joel nicely, you may have earned a snack.

Comment: I'm just as good a feeding the hunger than I am at creating it. Hit me up.

Answer (score 29):

Clear dem

[image]

Comment: Chocolate chip biscuits!

Comment: Clearing cookies still doesn't fix the fact that there's a glaring programming error in SE's code..

Comment: @cybermonkey there's a glaring error on the website. The error on the code might not be so obvious...

Comment: mmm morning snack time methinks...

Comment: Ummmm, _cooooookieeees_! 8-@